# Redundant gateway with same IP

Tags: networking, ip-address, gateway

I have a need where a physical site requires redundant control hardware.

Assume 10 devices require control signal to be sent to it from a master controller. If this controller for some reason goes down, I require a secondary controller to take its place.

During this transition, I would like the controller to have a common IP address. Otherwise the end devices require an update which is tedious.

So what are the options I have if I require two controllers to potentially have the same IP, if not simultaneously, at least on switchover.

Answer (score 0):

We have many such setups running and we typically use `keepalived`, as it provides fast and reliable failover while being very easy to configure and maintain.

If the machines in question are Windows, we typically do this within a routing layer in between, that also helps isolating the often vulnerable Windows hosts from the rest of the network.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll read up on it.